# ffmpeg - help understanding + correcting error message

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I have a python script that takes a movie file name and it does it job of splitting and converting videos. However, there are red error messages that constantly pop up on the console saying:

```
[buffer @ 0xa124320] Buffering several frames is not supported. Please consume all available frames before adding a new one.
```

How can i correct this? Is there something i need to do to the videos before running ffmpeg on them? Worse, i have the screenshot below where some message gets repeated THOUSANDS of times, slowing down everything!

[image: A repeating (error) message which essentially slows down the splitting and converting of video files]

Any help or insight is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What settings are you using for ffmpeg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like there's a problem with how your python script is interfacing with ffmpeg, or your ffmpeg settings.

If you're just interested in *suppressing* the console output, you could simply redirect the `stderr` of the python/ffmpeg process to `/dev/null`.  Of course, that will prevent you seeing any errors from ffmpeg, which may or may not be okay for your purposes.